# Datetime Difference in MySQL when format is Varchar

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, datatypes

I have two columns in a table: `STOP` and `START`, of type `varchar`.

I want to have the difference between both columns, and I'm using :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(stop, start) AS difference from T1;
```

It is giving me `null`, because of different data types.

To test, I also tried:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('5/16/2011 20:14 PM', '%c %e %Y %H:%i:%s');
```

It is also giving `null`.

What should I do for the difference? I have `n` number of data and time in different formats.

[image]

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings? There is a `date` and a `datetime` datatype.

Comment: I have three questions: 1) Is the time format for the `start` column in every row the same format? 2) Is the time format for the `stop` column in every row the same format? 3) What is the year for the stop column? (I ask this because if you start 2013-12-31 23:59:59 and stop 2014-01-01 00:00:01, this implies the Year 2014)

Comment: @ypercube - because format is entirely different that we have in datetime and timestamp datatype..i tried this one as well , but couldnt find any difference and such data is incremental data , increasing to lakh and crores..

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA - 1. Yes 2. Same 3. Oops , there is no year , we have to add current year here as well..

Comment: well we can assume 2013 year in stop column

Comment: Another question, if day of the month < 10, is the day zero-padded? in other words, does Jan 9th appear with '9' or '09' ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to unify all Date and Time Stamps into one format for both `start` and `stop`.

Just to give you an example, I'll compute the time difference for the first row.

Here is the code to compute it:

```
SET @StartDT = 'Mon Jan 21, 21:07:47 IST 2013';
SET @StopDT  = 'Tue Jan 22, 07:59:58';
SET @YYYY_Start = SUBSTR(@StartDT,-4);
SET @MMM_Start  = RIGHT(LEFT(@StartDT,7),3);
SET @DD_Start   = RIGHT(LEFT(@StartDT,10),2);
SET @HMS_Start  = RIGHT(LEFT(@StartDT,20),8);
SET @YYYY_Stop  = SUBSTR(@StartDT,-4);
SET @MMM_Stop   = RIGHT(LEFT(@StopDT,7),3);
SET @DD_Stop    = RIGHT(LEFT(@StopDT,10),2);
SET @HMS_Stop   = RIGHT(LEFT(@StopDT,20),8);
SET @MM_Start   = RIGHT(LEFT((LOCATE(@MMM_Start,'JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDev')+2)/3+100,3),2);
SET @MM_Stop    = RIGHT(LEFT((LOCATE(@MMM_Stop,'JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDev')+2)/3+100,3),2);
SELECT @YYYY_Start,@YYYY_Stop,@MM_Start,@MM_Stop,@DD_Start,@DD_Stop,@HMS_Start,@HMS_Stop,@MM_Start,@MM_Stop;
SET @YYYMMDD_Start = CONCAT(@YYYY_Start,'-',@MM_Start,'-',@DD_Start);
SET @YYYMMDD_Stop  = CONCAT(@YYYY_Stop,'-',@MM_Stop,'-',@DD_Stop);
SET @TS_Start = CONCAT(@YYYMMDD_Start,' ',@HMS_Start);
SET @TS_Stop  = CONCAT(@YYYMMDD_Stop,' ',@HMS_Stop);
SET @TimeDiffSec = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@TS_Stop) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@TS_Start); 
SET @TimeDiff = SEC_TO_TIME(@TimeDiffSec); 
SELECT @TS_Start,@TS_Stop,@TimeDiffSec,@TimeDiff;
```

Ready to see the difference? Here it is:

```
mysql> SET @StartDT = 'Mon Jan 21, 21:07:47 IST 2013';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @StopDT  = 'Tue Jan 22, 07:59:58';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @YYYY_Start = SUBSTR(@StartDT,-4);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @MMM_Start  = RIGHT(LEFT(@StartDT,7),3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @DD_Start   = RIGHT(LEFT(@StartDT,10),2);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @HMS_Start  = RIGHT(LEFT(@StartDT,20),8);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @YYYY_Stop  = SUBSTR(@StartDT,-4);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @MMM_Stop   = RIGHT(LEFT(@StopDT,7),3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @DD_Stop    = RIGHT(LEFT(@StopDT,10),2);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @HMS_Stop   = RIGHT(LEFT(@StopDT,20),8);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @MM_Start   = RIGHT(LEFT((LOCATE(@MMM_Start,'JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDev')+2)/3+100,3),2);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @MM_Stop    = RIGHT(LEFT((LOCATE(@MMM_Stop,'JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDev')+2)/3+100,3),2);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @YYYY_Start,@YYYY_Stop,@MM_Start,@MM_Stop,@DD_Start,@DD_Stop,@HMS_Start,@HMS_Stop,@MM_Start,@MM_Stop;
+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| @YYYY_Start | @YYYY_Stop | @MM_Start | @MM_Stop | @DD_Start | @DD_Stop | @HMS_Start | @HMS_Stop | @MM_Start | @MM_Stop |
+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 2013        | 2013       | 01        | 01       | 21        | 22       | 21:07:47   | 07:59:58  | 01        | 01       |
+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @YYYMMDD_Start = CONCAT(@YYYY_Start,'-',@MM_Start,'-',@DD_Start);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @YYYMMDD_Stop  = CONCAT(@YYYY_Stop,'-',@MM_Stop,'-',@DD_Stop);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @TS_Start = CONCAT(@YYYMMDD_Start,' ',@HMS_Start);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @TS_Stop  = CONCAT(@YYYMMDD_Stop,' ',@HMS_Stop);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @TimeDiffSec = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@TS_Stop) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@TS_Start);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @TimeDiff = SEC_TO_TIME(@TimeDiffSec);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Final Answer

```
mysql> SELECT @TS_Start,@TS_Stop,@TimeDiffSec,@TimeDiff;
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------+
| @TS_Start           | @TS_Stop            | @TimeDiffSec | @TimeDiff |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 2013-01-21 21:07:47 | 2013-01-22 07:59:58 |        39131 | 10:52:11  |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Even though this is right, it would be illogical to script this convoluted method for all rows, especially since some rows have different formats.

Therefore, it is in your best interest to convert `start` and `stop` columns into `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: well..a long explanation..thanks for your assistance..i want to appreciate ..can you please tell me how should i use format as per me..for ex. as in datetime & timestamp data type, format is specific...and if i need to customize it..how should i do it ?? also if i need to insert any date's format then it should insert in customized format only...how should i do this